# Array values are suddenly changing

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a weird problem right now, so I have a Vector Class and I need to transform a 2D array containing 2D coordinates into an array of vectors but the values of the array are changing if I try to push them

```
 function Vector(x,y)
 {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
 }
 ....functions concerning vectors like magnitude etc.
 function setArray(coords)
 {
   var arrayOfVectors = [];
   for(var i = 0; i < coords.length; i++)
   {
      arrayOfVectors.push(new Vector(coords[i][0], coords[i][1]));
   }
    return arrayOfVectors;
 }
```

Now if I try setArray([[130,130]]) the result is an array with a vector with x:110 and y:110, how does this happen?

Thanks

Comment: Your code is incomplete; cannot reproduce.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This isn't enough? I don't have more except function concerning vector properties

Comment: `This isn't enough?`  Not if we can't reproduce it.  Are you able to create a snippet with the problem.

Comment: This code seems to work fine to me (except for the uncommented comment)

Comment: That code works as expected. Either you're doing something wrong and not showing it on the question or you just messed up your inputs

Comment: When/where/how are you inspecting the array? You seem to be mutating the vector objects in between (or at some point).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]I copied and pasted your code into repl.it. It seemed to work just fine. Make sure you're inputs are correct.
Try Console logging the values in the constrructor as they're being set.